# centering right side with autoaligne

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}
    \[
    (S):\quad
    \left\{
    \autoaligne{x-2y+3z-4t=4\\+y-z+t=\-3\\x+3y+-3t=1\\+\-y+3z+t=\-3}
    \right.
    \]
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

I would like the right side (4,-3,1,-3) to be centered. Is there an option in the `autoaligne` package? I didn't find anything

Comment: It works if you append an `\hfil` to every line, for example, end the first line with ``=4\hfil\\``.

Comment: @Didier Why would you want to do that? The current layout looks perfect. Just to see the difference: Replace `4` by `4\ ` (backslash space added), and `1` by `1\ `. The result is not an improvement.

Comment: When there is a -(a+1) and a 5, for instance, I find the centered alignment better.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you. It works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `systeme`, not `autoaligne`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
(S):\quad
\sysalign{r,c}
\systeme[xyzt]{
  x-2y+3z-4t=4,
  y-z+t=-3,
  x+3y-3t=1,
 -y+3z+t=-(a+1)
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I test your solution (using up-to date MIKTeX)  in the fresh test document, I get error: `! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.`. What is going wrong?

Comment: @Zarko Check your test document. I can't test MiKTeX, sorry.

Comment: @Zarko You might have a file called `system.tex` in the search path. Check which one is loaded.

Comment: I check my MiKTeX installation and didn't find any file like system.tex, However for test I create subfolder `systeme` and named document as `systeme`. Now I change this names, clear all .aux files and now your example works. So, I'm a bit confused what happening in my tests. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, you should look for `systeme.tex`, because `systeme.sty` just does `\input systeme.tex`. Indeed, calling the test file `systeme.tex` was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for comment. Now I bit clean-up (a bit) my MiKTeX installation so I can live with it till to time when I would by new PC (this is eighteen old and quite slow). Then I would very carefully make fresh installation of it. +1 for your help in proposed solution.

Comment: Thank you @egreg. I know the `systeme` package. That’s what I was using before. But, a year ago, I wrote to the author of the package because I had a question, and he answered me to use `autoaligne` instead, because `systeme` was deprecated . So I will keep using `autoaligne` because I don’t want to change all my linear systems

Comment: @Didier I find that `autoaligne` is no substitute for `systeme`.

Comment: @egreg I don't know but I think that what you can do with `systeme`, you can also do it with `autoaligne` and the opposite is not true. I found the answer to my question. If I type `\autoaligne[dc]{...}`, it works

Comment: @Didier With much more awkward syntax.